# Removing missing webpart /feature references

Tags: 2007, web-part, migration

I have a question, basically i did a preupgrade check on my sharepoint 2007 and i got list of webparts which are not used anymore (are referenced but are missing), how do i delete them or how do i find them to delete, i only have guids.

Same goes to some solutions and features.

I mean i get the guid's of that stuff but how do i basically rally delete them? Normally when the wsp is rectracted shouldn't it delete all this objects from the sharepoint?

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detach and re attach the content DB.

you can try the codeplex tool for this

[SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/)

If features are not deactived before removal they stay as an orphan in the system (contentdb) and can cause issues lateron. You can use the poweshell code from the below Wiki Article to remove the orphan stuff.

The procedure for identyfing and removing orphaned features is quite straightforward:

- Go through every site collection and site recursively
- For each SPWebApp, SPSite and SPWeb
- Iterate through the *.Features collection
- For each feature, if the definition is null the script removes it
  from the feature collection
  [SharePoint 2007: How to Remove Orphaned Features Using PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8027.sharepoint-2007-how-to-remove-orphaned-features-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool - Yes, very good tool.

Comment: so for the features i should execute that tool to clean it up, and for the web parts and other stuff, i just have to use that powershell? Is this before or after attaching/detaching content database?

Comment: in many cases detach and attach fix the issue. That Tool help you remove all the orphan stuff...so basically you have 3 workaround....

Answer (score 0):

Retracting a WSP will not remove deployed web parts or deactivate site or web features. You can remove missing features using the FeatureAdmin tool: http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/

For the Web Parts you should be getting the filename in the logs (.dwp or .webpart). Then you can look all Site Collections and remove the file from the Web Part catalog (/_catalogs/wp).